# Get Plans returns 401 - Unauthorized

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am new to Microsoft Graph. I wanted to create a console app which will fetch all the Group Ids based on a Group Name and then fetch a particular Plan Id with that Group Id and Plan Name (I may or may not be a member of that group).

I have written a code which is able to fetch group Id but when I try to use it to fetch the Plan Id:

```
var targetGroup = await _graphClient
    .Groups
    .Request()
    .Filter($"startsWith(displayName,'{groupName}')")
    .GetAsync();

var groupId = targetGroup.First().Id;

var plans = await _graphClient
    .Groups[groupId]
    .Planner
    .Plans
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

This last line fires an exception:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

I am using the O365 E3 Trial version. I have read all the solutions posted here and tried them but the error is still there. I have allowed all the permissions (Delegated and Application) for Users, Tasks, Directory, Files, and Groups.

Could it be a problem with permissions or the trail version?

Update:

I also tried this:

`GraphHttpClient.MicrosoftGraphV1BaseUri + $"groups/{groupId}/planner/plans";`

It works fine for `groupId` but when I add `/planner/plans` it throws the same exception.

Comment: How are you obtaining the token?

Comment: I followed the steps given here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/dotnetcore-console-sample/tree/master/base-console-app but instead of using appconfig.json I wrote client Id and other IDs in <appsettings> in app.config in VS2015 solution

Comment: So, as given in the link I am not using LoadAppSettings() or config for that matter. Just using the values by ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["Value"]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using User access token or Application token? Because that api (GET /groups/{group-id}/planner/plans) it's not supported for Application token according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannergroup-list-plans?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
I'm not sure for User access token but I think you must be a member of the group to reach out to plans.

Comment: I am using User delegated authorization.

Comment: Based on the same you provided a link to, this is incorrect. That sample is using Client Credentials (Application scopes).

Answer (score 1):

The sample code you've refferenced is using the Client Credentials OAuth grant. This will result in assigning Application scopes to your token rather than Delegate scopes:

```cs
AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
authResult = await _clientApplication
    .AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes) // This is "Client Credentials"
    .ExecuteAsync();
return authResult.AccessToken;
```

Specifically, the `AcquireTokenForClient` call is where this is happening. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplication.acquiretokenforclient?view=azure-dotnet):

> Acquires a token from the authority configured in the app, for the confidential client itself (in the name of no user) using the client credentials flow. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-client-credentials.

As Martin Jones stated in his answer, `/plans` [only supports Delegated permission scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannergroup-list-plans?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

- Delegated (work or school account): `Group.Read.All`, `Group.ReadWrite.All`
- Delegated (personal Microsoft account): **Not supported**.
- Application: **Not supported**.

In order to call `/plans`, you will need to acquire a token using a different OAuth Grant which supports Delegated permissions such as [`AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplication.acquiretokenonbehalfof?view=azure-dotnet) or [`AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplication.acquiretokenbyauthorizationcode?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: Are there any other methods to acquire token which supports Delegated permissions? Does AcquireTokenAsync support delegated permissions?
                                                                                                                            
   **result = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credentials);
     var accessToken = result.AccessToken;**

Comment: I am thinking of creating an admin account and keep it as a part of every group and then use this context to acquire tokens.

Comment: There is no way to authenticate without a user and still use delegated scopes (after all, _who_ would be delegating you permission in that case?).

Comment: Yes, I understand. I read this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#2-get-authorization. I just want a reference code to understand how the process is working. Do you know some link where I could see the actual working code to get an Authorization code and then using it to acquire tokens?

Comment: I hit this wall today too. I was not really sure if I had to acquire another access token on behalf of a user or switch from client credentials to user credentials altogether (because as a user, using graph explorer, /planner/plans works), or what to do. Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to use multiple tokens for this (one Delegaed and another Application). This allows you \to use higher privileged operations without requesting overly broad access to the tenant.